# Errors with Demos / Scripts in Google Elements Package

Tags: google-vr

**[Introduction]**

I'm working with Unity (rather beginner level, but I've gotten a lot of the basics down), and I was interested in seeing the Teleportation demos implemented by Google and I was curious to see how I could do something similar.  The first step to that is getting the Teleportation demo to work I suppose though!

**[The Issue]**

Whenever I try to compile the demo or even just a Scene that uses some of its prefabs (in particular, GVRControllerPointer prefab), I get about 15 errors that all stem from 2 main issues.

**[The Error Images]**

Here's what they look like:
[List of errors1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMXpH.png)
[List of errors2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GErC.png)

**[Examples of some of the Errors]**

So essentially, I'm getting errors that stem from GVRControllerButton, and VisualAssets.

**"Assets/GoogleVR/Scripts/Controller/GvrControllerInputDevice.cs(187,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `GvrControllerButton' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?"**

**"Assets/GoogleVR/Beta/Scripts/GvrBetaControllerVisualMulti.cs(22,13): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `VisualAssets' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?"**

**"Assets/GoogleVR/Scripts/Controller/Internal/ControllerUtils.cs(25,28): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `GvrControllerHand' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?"**

Sorry for the jumble of errors, but those are the main issues occurring with VisualAssets and GvrControllerButton as the main two issues.

Am I missing something?  Maybe I'm just not loading the demo scene properly? I'm not too sure.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question needs to be more relevant

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently. I found that reimporting the latest GVR SDK (v1.180.0) fixed these errors.

Alternatively, try creating a new project in Unity, switch to the Android platform and then import the Google Elements package (I'm using Unity 2018.2.8f1), before adding anything else to the scene.